# How to print arrays in Laravel with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, laravel

I recieve an array with AjaxPetitions Array[0],Array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mFHt.png), Array[2] and recieve the information correctly.

```
$.ajax({
                url:'obtenersubastas',
                dataType:'json',
                type:'get',
                cache:true,
                success:  function (response) {
                    $(response).each(function(index,value)  {
                            console.log(response[index].nombre);
                            console.log(response[index].descripcion);
                            console.log(response[index].cant_actual);
                            console.log(response[index].images);
                            console.log(response[index].data_final);
                            console.log(response[index].id);
                    });

                },              
        });
```

I need to send this information to a class called .nombre html , could anyone helps to me ?

**UPDATE**

with append I have a problem , i need to follow a style in the page and the result is this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $('.nombre').html() to add your values in the selector element.

Try this code

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'obtenersubastas',
            dataType:'json',
            type:'get',
            cache:true,
            success:  function (response) {
                $(response).each(function(index,value)  {
                       $('.nombre').append('<p>Nombre :' +response[index].nombre +' descripcion: '+ response[index].descripcion + ' cant_actual: '+response[index].cant_actual +' images : '+ response[index].images +' data_final: '+ response[index].data_final +' id :'+ response[index].id+'</p>');
                });

            },              
    });
```

Comment: With this form , I only can show one elemente of the array , specifically the last one.

Comment: @jcsa , instead of .html(), you can use .append() to get all data.

Comment: I did this chang and I explain the problem now @Bhavin Solanki

Comment: To @jcsa i have update code for this issue. I have add **P** tag for each new record

Comment: I have a problem because I use bootstrap3 and I need to append in a column, but thanks for your answer to add all content to html I need to use .appned and no .html @Bhavin Solanki

Comment: @jcsa Happy to help......i think you need to use some bootstrap class to get proper output. If you like my answer please up vote and accept, if you would like....